# Bypass CloudFront cache

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way for certain users to force a bypass of CloudFront's cache so that they can always request new versions of files from the source, but the  new files that they request are then available on the cache to other normal-permission users?

For example, if I had a sports score app that cached score information for 5 minutes, but I wanted to add a premium tier that allows subscribers to download up-to-date data whenever they use the app. I'd still want the data that the premium users download to be cached on CloudFront so that regular users don't waste API calls into the servers.

I was thinking maybe there would be a way to do this in the request headers, but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Is it possible to generate random token each time Premium users open their app and makes the request with including a custom header and the token in your app ? You can whitelist this so  Premium user will come with the random header each time  and it'll a miss from CloudFront, on the other side, normal user doesn't come with this header at all so a separate cache key will be for them (yet the first request will go to the server though), the other option is similar but with cookies and whitelist specific cookie for premium users .

Comment: Hmm, would the files downloaded by the premium users still show up in the cache for the regular users? Or would premium and regular users be downloading files from two separate caches?

Comment: No, not for the normal users, a first request from a normal user needs to go to the server in order to cache it on CloudFront but rest of other normal requests will be served from the cache, separate cache keys for normal and premium users.

Comment: Is your application already using CloudFront?  The cache is not monolithic -- it's distributed, and has two tiers -- so I wonder if you have a sense of your current hit/miss statistics.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting around 40% hits right now.

Comment: Hey @bmueller have you solved this issue? How?